# deegree WMS incomplete ServiceException code="InvalidRequest"

Tags: wms, deegree

I'm new in GIS and trying to explore WMS and WFS implemented by deegree [Version deegree-webservices-3.3.20]. I followed all the steps mentioned at http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.3.19/html/installation.html for deployment on Windows (deployed on Windows 7 64 bit machine).

I'm getting a response for WMS request:

```
< ?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'? >
< ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" >
  < ServiceException code="InvalidRequest" >
```

which is incomplete response in itself.

I could see some error message in log file "localhost.2017-05-03.log":

---

```
May 03, 2017 3:21:52 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession writeObject
WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute configManager for session AC90FBED92FB2432CD19E034F3469DAE
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.deegree.console.ResourceManagerMetadata2
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1551)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:994)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:523)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:450)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:692)
```

---

For your information, I set-up feature from a shapefile. WMS request which I used is:
http://localhost:8080/services/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&Layers=MySampleLayer&SRS=epsg:4326&BBOX=-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735&width=256&height=256&styles=&format=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

It would be very helpful if anybody can help me on this issue. I'm not able to move further just because of this issue :(

Same shapefile works perfectly in GeoServer with same WMS request.

Comment: Have you tried with uppercase `EPSG=4326`?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, I tried with EPSG4326 [uppercase], but it didn't work :(

Comment: Is there anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at your configuration it's hard to tell what's the problem. Is your service configuration actually called 'wms.xml'? Try requesting

http://localhost:8080/services?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&Layers=MySampleLayer&SRS=epsg:4326&BBOX=-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735&width=256&height=256&styles=&format=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

(without the /wms after services)